# ssh "-P" option, what's it used for?

Tags: ssh

In an old (2001?) script for the Linux OS I've encountered the use of the `-P` option for the `ssh` command:

```
$ ssh -P host.domain -l user
```

But in the `ssh` manual page there's no mention of a `-P` option. Nevertheless, executing `ssh -P host.domain` doesn't show any warning or error.

What's it? Could be an old/undocumented option?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Old version man page:

> -P
>
> Use non privileged port. With this you cannot use rhosts or rsarhosts authentications, but it can be used to bypass some firewalls that dont allow privileged source ports to pass.
>
> [...]
>
> UsePrivilegedPort
>
> Specifies whether to use privileged port when connecting to other end. The default is yes if rhosts or rsarhosts authentications are enabled.

Straight from the source code:

```
            case 'P':       /* deprecated */
                    options.use_privileged_port = 0;
                    break;
```

It sets the option to 0, which seems to be the default value anyway, so it does nothing. Ignoring deprecated options helps backwards compatibility in cases where it does not affect functionality...

The `/* deprecated */` change dates back to 2002-09-04.

---

Even the bit of code I quoted above (from openssh-portable 7.7) just about [got removed in a recent commit](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/95d41e90eafcd1286a901e8e361e4a37b98aeb52):

> upstream: Deprecate UsePrivilegedPort
>
> now that support for running
>   ssh(1) setuid has been removed, remove supporting code and clean up
>   references to it in the man pages
>
> We have not shipped ssh(1) the setuid bit since 2002.  If ayone
>   really needs to make connections from a low port number this can
>   be implemented via a small setuid ProxyCommand.
>
> ok markus@ jmc@ djm@
>
> OpenBSD-Commit-ID: d03364610b7123ae4c6792f5274bd147b6de717e

It still ignores the option but no longer even sets an internal variable to go with it.